# Problema Java = java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

Tags: java, array

Primero antes que nada, se que hay un post en Stackoverflow acerca de este mismo problema, pero no pudo solucionar el problema que yo tenia, basicamente el problema es este que mencione en el titulo. Segun lo que lei es porque estoy intentando acceder a una posicion de la matriz que no existe, pero el "Error" sale solo cuando estoy inicializando una variable. Aqui dejo el case del problema:

```
case 4: //Suma
    int hasta1 = columna1+columna2;
    int hasta2 = fila1+fila2;
    int suma = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<hasta1; i++) {
        for (int k=0; k<hasta2; k++) {
            suma=vector1[i][k]+vector2[i][k];
        }
    }
    System.out.print("La suma de todos los numeros cargados en ambas matrices da como resultado = ");
    System.out.println(suma);
    break;
```

Desde ya, muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda

Comment: Si nos colocas el stacktrace nos ayudas mucho. Por otro lado con el código que nos compartes no se ve que valores tienen columna1, columna2, fila1 y fila2 al momento del error. Tampoco se saben las dimensiones de vector1 y vector2.  Con más información obtendras una mejor respuesta.

Comment: Como es eso de Stacktrace? @AlvaroC.

Comment: El stacktrace es la traza del error completa.

Comment: Si `fila1` y `fila2` representan el número de filas de las matrices `vector1` y `vector2` respectivamente, entonces el índice `i` de tu primer bucle `for` se sale de ambas dimensiones para cada matriz. Lo mismo ocurre para el índice `k` que representa las columnas. Por ello el error de *índice fuera de límites*. Saludos

Comment: Por otro lado, aún cuando corrijas el problema de los índices, tienes el problema que tu variable suma siempre será la suma de los dos últimos elementos encontrados en el recorrido de ambas matrices, ya que no estás acumulando (con el operador `suma += valor`) sino que sólo estás asignando (con el operador `suma = valor`). Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como decís el error se debe a que estas tratando de acceder a una posición de la matriz/array que no existe.

El problema principal es que estas tratando de iterar a partir de una variable externa al array. La condición de corte del **for** debería estar delimitada por el tamaño del array y no por una variable cuyo valor es calculado. Es decir, usar *vector1.lenght()* en lugar de *hasta1* y lo mismo para *vector2*.

```javascript
for (int i=0; i<vector1.length(); i++) {
        for (int k=0; k<vector2.lenth(); k++) {
            suma=vector1[i][k]+vector2[i][k];
        }
    }
```

O bien podrías inicializar *hasta1* y *hasta2* con el correspondiente valor de iteracion:

```javascript
int hasta1 = vector1.length();
int hasta2 = vector2.length();
```

A lo que voy con esto: si tengo *vector1* que es una matriz 5x3, el número máximo de filas a recorrer debería ser 5 y el máximo de columnas a recorrer deberían ser 3. Es decir, tu *hasta1* debería ser igual a 3 y *hasta2* igual a 5. La suma que haces debería dar dichos valores para que no surja el error.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes clarificar que representan los valores de fila1, columna1, fil2, columna2? Si estos representan las dimensiones de vector1[][] y vector2[][] respectivamente, estonces ese es uno de los problemaa con tu codigo.

Asumiendo the vector1[][] y vector2[][] son de igual dimension, solo necesitas

```
int hasta1 = columna1;
int hasta2 = fila1;
```

Puedes mostrar la declaracion de tus arreglos? Tiene que ser algo como:

```
int vector1[columna1][fila1]
int vector2[columna2][file2]
```

fijate en el order de las dimensiones, si estan invertidas tambien producira una exception por la violacion en las dimensiones del arreglo ("Out of Bounds")

Otro problema latente es si vector1[][] y vector2[] son de diferentes dimensiones. En ese caso, lo mas probable es que la logica detras de tu codigo esta equivocada. Por que necesitas sumar dos matrices de dimensiones diferentes, si este es el caso?